# How to use Troisjs in Nuxt 3 project

Tags: vue.js, three.js, nuxt.js

I would like to use `TroisJS` (`three.js` wrapper for Vue) with `Nuxt.js`. According to the `TroisJS` documentation (https://troisjs.github.io/guide/install.html#existing-vuejs-3-project) I need to add it to my project like:

```
import { TroisJSVuePlugin } from 'troisjs';
app.use(TroisJSVuePlugin);
```

However, I don"t know how to figure out where I should put this code. I would expect the nuxt.config.js file, but I don't seem to quite get it where it should go.

I decided to use `TroisJS` and not `three.js` because I thought the former might be easier to import and use. If importing `three.js` directly is easier, I don't mind using it.

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: I'm not sure that mixing Nuxt and Trois is relevant. You should probably keep Trois standalone or import ThreeJS into Nuxt but having both seems quite heavy and redundant to me.

Comment: I don't know what the best approach is. i want to create a website with mulriple sites and i thought nuxt is better for that. also it seems to automate a lot of the undocumented vue setup-code. vue and apparently also nuxt make it really hard to integrate other code. it is so much easier with jquery.

Comment: I don't really agree about jQuery being simpler. And Nuxt is totally working with any Vue plugin. The mix of Nuxt and Trois is just not relevant IMO.

Comment: why is the mix not relevant. i want to work with 3d and vue. Trois is like a wrapper for three.js, is it not? so this makes it easier to use three.js in a vue app.

i use nuxt to make to vue workflow easier and because it has better support for websites with multiple sites.

i know that this is getting kinda convoluted, but isn't my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 0):

In `/plugins` folder add new file named `troisjs-plugin.js` with the following content :

```js
import { TroisJSVuePlugin } from 'troisjs';

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(TroisJSVuePlugin )
})
```

Comment: i have created a new directory called plugins because i did not have one before. there i created the file and with the content you mentioned. to test if it was working i added the following example: https://troisjs.github.io/guide/install.html#example

after opening the site, it showed the text: renderer.onBeforeRender is not a function.

is nuxt compatible with standard vue plugins, or do i have to switch to vue to use them?

Answer (score 0):

I found a repo with some testing with Trois and Nuxt 3, probably outdated and maybe some apis have changed, but if you wanna check it out: [alvarosabu/nuxt3-trois](https://github.com/alvarosabu/nuxt3-trois)

Also, there's an official repo from the Trois author with a Nuxt 3 custom plugin (probably outdated too) [here](https://github.com/troisjs/nuxt3-test)